# Why will this if statement not work? Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, string

```
@implementation ViewController
-(IBAction)changelabel {
NSString *string1 =entername.text;
NSString *string2 =@"Alan Shearer";
NSString *string3 =@"Alan Shearer 260 Goals";

if([string1 isEqualToString:string2])

{label.text=string3;}
}
```

I want it so, when the user enters "Alan Shearer" into a text field it changes the label to Alan Shearer

Answer (score 1):

Add a sender to your method

```
-(IBAction)changeLabel:(id)sender
```

Comment: I have done so, it still does not work and it shows no errors.  When I run the app, and press check, it closes the app.

Answer (score 0):

What does `NSLog(@"%@", string1)` write? Your NSString comparison method is right.

Comment: How do I view NSLog?  There are no errors and it still does not work and it shows no errors.  When I run the app, and press check, it closes the app.

Comment: Just add this piece of code before your `if` statement and look in console output.

Comment: that obviously means the method is not called, which indicates you didn't make up a connection with the `IBAction`.